# wp_enqueue_style will not let me enforce screen only

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, theme-roots

I am using Roots as the starter for a theme I have been working on. I then generated a print.css file, but in Chrome's case, it still is using the bootstrap-responsive.css queries, and messing things up.

This [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955718/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-print-thumbnails-as-same-as-screen) explains the issue, and I know it fixes what I am having an issue with (tried it).

What happens is that when using this

```
wp_enqueue_style('roots_bootstrap_responsive_style', '/css/bootstrap-responsive.css', array('roots_bootstrap_style'), null, 'screen');
```

It always puts out

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
```

When I really need it to show

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" media="screen">
```

If I try some of the [other types listed on W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types), some work and some don't (TV doesn't ever render anything, but print does). For example, my print one works fine:

```
wp_enqueue_style('roots_print_style', '/css/print.css', false, null, 'print');
```

How can I get this to work? Do I just do this in the header without using wp_enqueue_style, or am I missing something? I do not get any errors, and using WP 3.5.1.

Comment: That code works when I try it on 3.5.1 with Twenty Twelve-- so does using `TV` or `nada`. I'd guess the problem is Roots or a badly built plugin.

Comment: Thats what I was worried about. We aren't using many plugins, so I will disable those first.

Comment: Is this causing errors or issues on the frontend or is this just an attempt to get markup to look a certain way?

Comment: Chrome uses the media queries in bootstrap-responsive when trying to print. So no rendering issues, except when printing. Getting the markup right would solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. [Roots has a roots_clean_style_tag](https://github.com/retlehs/roots/blob/master/lib/cleanup.php#L97-L106) that limits everything except print as a media type.

I updated mine slightly to just allow screen as well:

```
function roots_clean_style_tag($input) {
  preg_match_all("!<link rel='stylesheet'\s?(id='[^']+')?\s+href='(.*)' type='text/css' media='(.*)' />!", $input, $matches);
  // Only display media if it's print
  if($matches[3][0] === 'print'){
      $media = ' media="print"';
  } elseif ($matches[3][0] === 'screen'){
      $media = ' media="screen"';
  }
  else{
      $media = '';
  }

  //$media = $matches[3][0] === 'print' ? ' media="print"' : '';
  return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $matches[2][0] . '"' . $media . '>' . "\n";
```